# How do these pieces of Predator equipment work?

Tags: predator-series, alien-vs.-predator, predator

I was wondering if anyone could tell me:

- How the Predators Plasma Caster works.
- How the Bio Mask changes vision modes.
- Finally how the Wrist Blades and Combi-Stick extend and retract.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer. Are you asking how they would work in reality, how they work in the films or how the props work?

Comment: I mean in the films sorry if you didnt understand ;-)

Comment: I'm still unclear what you mean. If you're just after general info you should read the AVP wikia; http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: I mean how they work i.e. How the plasma caster fires and how the bio mask switches vision modes thats what im asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Predator Wikia the "[Plasma Caster](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Plasma_Caster)" is based on eye-tracking technology. The gun itself is shoulder-mounted and can be fired either using the wrist gauntlet or by some kind of hidden signal (such as a button inside the Biomask).

The [Bio-mask](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Bio-Mask) is a combination breather, video recorder and targeting system for the Plasma Caster. The various vision modes include EM, Infra-red (easily fooled by mud) and UV. The modes are themselves controlled from the Predator's gauntlet.

The [Wrist Blades](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Wrist_Blades) extend from sheaths that mount to the wrist. They're controlled by a button on the side of the wrist. In addition to acting as melee weapons, they can also be explosively fired at enemies

The [Combi-Stick](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Combi-Stick) is a lightweight weapon that telescopes to form a spear-like object that can either be used as a pike or thrown at an opponent. They have an [LED-lit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voUzb.jpg) on the side that seems to activate the extension mechanism

Comment: Ok thanks! By the way do you think you could explain how the predator changes vision modes for me if its not to much to ask? (and anyone else who is reading this and wants to know)

Comment: Oh sorry dude i didnt realise you said it was controlled by the gauntlet